# __attribute__ ((__constructor__)) in android

Tags: android, c, gcc, constructor, android-ndk

I am trying to develop on android NDK. 
I actually have a project + subfolder with modules (compiled as static libraries) and linked together with the main project files (libs .a + main object .o --> executable). Everything done via ndk-build.

I am trying to make use of constructors, after digging for some hours I figured out that constructors are NOT called as long as a function of that lib (.o) is not invoked.

e.g.

```
__attribute__ ((__constructor__))
 void pre_func(void) {
        printf("pre_func2\n");
}

void my_init(){
printf ("tutto funge!");
//return 0;
}
```

called only when (and before) `my_init();` is explicitly invoked in `test.c`

```
$ adb shell /data/local/tmp/test
pre_func2
tutto funge!
```

now, my issue is very simple. By architecture I need some modules I prepared to be initialized when the object is loaded... I searched several stuff `(--init, _init())` none of them helps.

Since the same code on standard `linux (glibc and no bionic linker)` looks to work fine, is there something wrong in my compilation gcc statement which avoids the constructor to be executed at .a loading time? how can I solve?

Compile thumb  :

```
modules <= libtest.c
    /opt/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-        linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/modules/libtest.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -Ijni/modules -DANDROID -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/modules/libtest.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/modules/libtest.o 
    StaticLibrary  : libmodules.a
    rm -f obj/local/armeabi/libmodules.a
    /opt/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar crs ./obj/local/armeabi/libmodules.a ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/modules/libtest.o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/modules/module.o
```

Comment: First check the output of `objdump -t <executable>` to see whether the symbols from the lib are still linked even if no function from the lib is called from the main executable.

Comment: NDK will use `--gc-sections` by default: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7217034/484441 . I suspect this will throw away the section containing the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is that if some `.o` is not called from test.c, it is not linked into the **test** executable. That's how the liner treats static libraries (`.a` files). To force all compilation units (a.k.a. `.o` files) to be present in the executable, use

```
-Wl,-whole-archive libmodules.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

for building. You can achieve this in NDK by specifying

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := modules
```

but I must confess that I have never tried this with `$(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)`. It works fine for `$(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`. If something goes wrong, simply write

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,-whole-archive $(PATH_TO_LIBMODULES)/libmodules.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

and don't forget to set `PATH_TO_LIBMODULES` correctly.